# GCP Can I Expose Kubernetes Cluster ExternalIP without LoadBalancer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-networking

I would like to maintain a very low-cost Kubernetes cluster on GCP. I am using a single node pool of e1-small instances. The monthly cost of this instance is $4.91 which is fine. But the problem is the ingress I am using to expose my node ports to an external-IP. The ingress instance uses a Google load balancer which costs around $18. Therefore, I am mostly paying to a useless load balancer which I really don't need. Is there a way that I can expose the IP addresses of those instances without the load balancer?

Comment: You can expose your service with nodeport and rech it directly. However, if you need to use ingress controler, you have to use Load balancer, or to manage yourselve your ingress controler in your cluster (based on NGINX for example)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere But I want to expose port 80 specificially to an external IP. I have a domain name and I am assigning port 80 to that domain. Is there a way I can bind EXTERINAL_IP:32322 to my domain.com port 80?

Comment: You define your ports in your deployment, service, and ingress yaml files.

Answer (score 2):

If you expose the nodePort externally, you will expose a port number 10k+. So not a port 80 or 443 for a website. You need to proxy the connection, with a loadbalancer by example.

A solution is to use Cloud Run as reverse proxy with NGINX for example. In this case, you can also use serverless VPC Connector and reach the service through the private IP in your VPC.

Answer (score 0):

### Add the ingress-nginx repository

```
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
```

### Use Helm to deploy an NGINX ingress controller

```
helm install $NGINX ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --namespace $NAMESPACE \
    --set controller.replicaCount=2 \
    --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux
```

That's your load balancer.

Now get yourself a certificate manager...

### Label the namespace to disable resource validation

```
kubectl label -n $NAMESPACE cert-manager.io/disable-validation=true
```

### Add the Jetstack Helm repository

```
helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io
```

### Install the cert-manager Helm chart

```
helm install cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
  --namespace $NAMESPACE \
  --set installCRDs=true \
  --set nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
  --set webhook.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
  --set cainjector.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux
```

Next you'll need to add a CA Cluster Issuer...

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: $EMAIL_ADDRESS
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt
    solvers:
    - http01:
      ingress:
        class: nginx
          podTemplate:
            spec:
              nodeSelector:
                "kubernetes.io/os": linux
```

### Apply CA Cluster Issuer

```
kubectl apply -f cluster-issuer.yaml
```

You'll also need an ingress and service yaml.

### Ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: $INGRESS_NAME
  namespace: $NAMESPACE
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: $NAMESPACE
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - $YOUR_DOMAIN
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: $YOUR_DOMAIN
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: $SERVICE_NAME
          servicePort: $SERVICE_PORT
```

### Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: $SERVICE_NAME
  namespace: $NAMESPACE
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: $NAMESPACE
    app.kubernetes.io/type: service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: fart
    port: $SERVICE_PORT
    targetPort: $SERVICE_PORT
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: $DEPLOYMENT_NAME
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: $NAMESPACE
```

It shouldn't cost anything more to deploy these resources.

If you're so concerned about costs you can deploy a fully functioning and publicly reachable cluster locally with minikube or micro-k8s.